# Can I store image bytes in Session in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, session, model-view-controller

In my project I am converting image into bytes. After converting into bytes, I have found that the byte size is around 30,000 to 50,000 bytes. Is it fine  to store this much amount of bytes in Session? Is it going to effect the application performance?

Comment: Not is not recommended to store such data in Session , you session should always consist of small or minis-clue data

Comment: Thanks, Soumen. One more quick question, If I convert these bytes into base64 string for ex see this line of code: (string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64Data);  
Session["UserProfile"] = imageDataURL; ) and then store into session?